# Fragment UI not displayed

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, fragment

So I am working on this android app and I put a `NavigatonDrawer` into it, which works fine. When an item from the drawer is selected the MainActivity is supposed to replace the `FrameLayout`, which is defined in the `activity_main.xml`. The problem is that when I replace the `FrameLayout` with the fragment the app force closes. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Here's the method that gets called whenever you select an item from the drawer:

```
    @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (position){
        case 0: //cal
            calFragment cal=new calFragment().newInstance();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, cal);
            break;
        case 1: //note
            noteFragment note=new noteFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, note);
            break;
        case 2: //con
            conFragment con=new conFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, con);
            break;
        case 3: //TODO login
            break;
        case 4: //TODO settings
            break;
        default:break;
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.arandum.syncc.MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.arandum.syncc.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

also the calFragment.java and the fragment_cal.xml for reference

```
public class calFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static calFragment newInstance() {
    calFragment fragment = new calFragment();
    return fragment;
}
public calFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cal, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.arandum.syncc.calFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_section1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />
```

Thanks in advance!

new

```
    04-15 11:23:49.385  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    04-15 11:23:49.445  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/ActivityThread;.mActiveResources
    04-15 11:23:49.445  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 1
    04-15 11:23:49.445  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0006
    04-15 11:23:49.445  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/ActivityThread;.mPackages
    04-15 11:23:49.445  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 4
    04-15 11:23:49.445  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0000
    04-15 11:23:49.560  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    04-15 11:23:49.560  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fd9ba8)
    04-15 11:23:49.565  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.arandum.syncc, PID: 22325
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arandum.syncc/com.arandum.syncc.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.arandum.syncc.MainActivity@42315fe8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
                at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5029)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.arandum.syncc.MainActivity@42315fe8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                at com.arandum.syncc.calFragment.onAttach(calFragment.java:36)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6050)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5029)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 11:23:51.490  22325-22325/com.arandum.syncc I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 22325 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a `FragmentTransaction` and *add/replace/show/hide* a `Fragment`, you always need to do a [`commit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29) as follows:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, cal).commit();
```

Then, your code should use a general variable for your Fragment as:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransac = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
// init the fragment (with the a default fragment, not null)
Fragment frag = new calFragment().newInstance();
switch (position){
    case 0:
        // init with the 1st fragment
        frag = new calFragment().newInstance();
        break;
    case 1:
        // init with the 2nd fragment
        frag = new noteFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        // same for others
        frag = new conFragment();
        break;
    case 3: //TODO login
        break;
    case 4: //TODO settings
        break;
    default:break;
}
// THEN replace with the fragment variable
fragmentTransac.replace(R.id.container, frag, null);
// commit the transaction
fragmentTransac.commit();
```

As your Logcat said: `com.arandum.syncc.MainActivity@42316ed0 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener` then try to add this implementation:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity (or ActionBarActivity) implements calFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

For each Fragment will use one, you must implement its own `Interface` inside your `MainActivity` as follows:

```
implements calFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, noteFragment.PublicInterface, conFragment.AnotherInterface, ...etc
```

Comment: I tried this and now my app just force closes as soon as the transaction is committed. Should I use something different than replace maybe? I'll edit the post right away.

Comment: @NDTS I updated answer. I suspect a FragmentTransaction error, which is called several time with the same variable. You just have to change the fragment instead of commit() all the time. Anyway, if this still doesn't work, you should edit your post as you said and provide the logcat.

Comment: I'll try this in a sec. I'm trying to post the logcat but the site says I have errors(?)

Comment: I uploaded a file with the logcat...I hope that's alright

Comment: @NDTS It's preferable to put this in your question. I'll do it for you ;)

Comment: thanks a lot :D oh it does not make any difference on which device I'm  testing my app, does it?

Comment: no unfortunately it still fcs...coudl it be something else that is wrong? maybe the calFragment itself?

Comment: @NDTS No, except if you're not provide the right target SDK in your manifest, however there is no difference by using another device. Do you have the same LogCat as before? If not, update your post. It's possible that it actually might be your Fragment which has an error. Also, you should avoid to use lowercase for your Fragments (it's better to call `CalFragment` etc) *[However, I don't think this is related to your actual issue]*. Let me know.

Comment: I updated the oogcat in the post and I'll keep the lower/upper case thing in mind

Comment: Well, it's a bit weird. For me, in one of my fragments I just use (eg:) `mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;` just below the super method inside onAttach without try/catch method and it works well. Like [this example](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) for `TaskFragment`. Try without try/catch..

Comment: Hi @NDTS did you find a solution? I thought your problem is this line: `onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)`. Do you have this method inside your Activity? It might be related. Hope this helps.

Comment: YES! I checked everything again and did everything you suggested and it works very nicely. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @NDTS Greaaat! That's good! Really glad to help. Could you accept my answer, please? :) Happy coding for the next step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
FramentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

To apply the transaction to the activity, you must call commit().

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FramentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
switch (position){
    case 0: //cal
        calFragment cal=new calFragment().newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, cal);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();  
        break;
    case 1: //note
        noteFragment note=new noteFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, note);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
    case 2: //con
        conFragment con=new conFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, con);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
    case 3: //TODO login
        break;
    case 4: //TODO settings
        break;
    default:break;
}
```